# How to I remove special characters and spaces on a textfield using PHP

Tags: php

I need to remove all special characters and spaces on a textfield for a form I'm building. How do I accomplish this in PHP.

Answer (score 40):

This really depends, I assume you are working with $_POST[] data and wish to sanitize those inputs?  If so I would definitely do something like:

```
$var = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $var);
```

That will strip out everything other than alpha/num, you can adjust the regex to include other characters if you wish.  Some great examples of commonly used regular expressions can be found at: [The RegEx Library](http://regexlib.com/)

If this isn't quite what you are looking for or have other questions let us know.

Comment: Yes I'm working with $_POST data the exact code I currently have is the following:

<input type="text" name="trTrPath" id="trTrPath" value="<?php echo KT_escapeAttribute($row_rstribute['trTrPath']); ?>" size="32" />
        
  <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldHint("trTrPath");?> <?php echo $tNGs->displayFieldError("tribute", "trTrPath"); ?>

How would I add the suggest code to that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Missing pattern delimiters in the regexp

Comment: Kemp can you please show what exactly is missing in on that code.

Comment: Benny: The forward slashes were missing, now fixed.

Comment: @Benny Perhaps after all these years this could be the accepted answer? ;)

Answer (score 10):

Use the following regex during processing of the data:

```
$data = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', "", $data);
```

This will remove all non-alphanumeric characters from the data.

Comment: Missing pattern delimiters in the regexp

Answer (score 8):

```
$specialChars = array(" ", "\r", "\n");
$replaceChars = array("", "", "");

$str = str_replace($specialChars, $replaceChars, $str);
```