# Trying to remove special characters in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a form that has some text inputs.  When I add them to my db I get a '\' character before each special character {', ", etc}.  I want to remove the '\' before entering the text into the DB but so far I have been unable to.  I tried doing in the PHP before I execute the query:

```
$title_str = str_replace('\'','',$_POST['main_title']);
```

But it did not work.

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like magic quotes are still turned on.  You should disable them.  http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php  Also, be sure to use prepared queries (with PDO or similar) when inserting data in your database to avoid SQL injection problems.

Comment: @Brad, thanks.  I am using prepared with PDO.  Is it safe to turn off magic_quotes?

Comment: This might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959877/how-to-i-remove-special-characters-and-spaces-on-a-textfield-using-php

Comment: @LuisP Magic quotes are deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and removed as of PHP 5.4. This is feature, which is failure, like register_globals.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely safe to turn of magic quotes... you are encouraged to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like magic quotes are still turned on. You should disable them.  This is a perfectly safe thing to do.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Also, be sure to use prepared queries (with PDO or similar) when inserting data in your database to avoid SQL injection problems.

Comment: thanks, that worked!  Btw, is this not a prepared query? `$sql = "INSERT INTO mytitle (titlename, titlesourcee, titlepepole, publish_date, titleside, img_link) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $sth=$db->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute(array($_POST['asurl'], $_POST['Otitle'], $_POST['source'], $_POST['OP_pub_date'], $_POST['side'], $_POST['img_url']));`??

Comment: @LuisP, Yes, that query is prepared, and inherently safe from first-order SQL injection.

Comment: @Bard, thanks, glad to hear it, I learned it from one of your earlier suggestions that you had made to me.  +1 to you my friend.