# Remove space and special character - Dropzone

Tags: php, dropzone.js

How can I do to remove the spaces and special characters after completing the UPLOAD?

```
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1     
$storeFolder = 'arquivos';           //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $targetFile = $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];           //5
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);                    //6
}
```

Comment: check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/a/2960312/4498937

Answer (score 2):

Simply alter this:

```
$targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
```

Add some name processing. This way you're both storing the file and changing the name in the same place.

```
$originalName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$safeName     = cleanNameFunction($originalName);
$targetFile   = $targetPath . $safeName;  //5
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile); //6
```

Where `cleanNameFunction` can strip whitespaces, for instance.
I usually go with stripping out everything except `a-zA-Z0-9`.

```
function cleanNameFunction($name){
    $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $name);
    return $name;
}
```